# fire back button in UINavigationcontroller with code

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How is it possible to get one level up in my navigationcontroller?
The docs didn't help me.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

pops to the root(as it says).

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

didn't work either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this function:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: i thought i already tried this, but with getting an error.

Thanks, now it works :)